# Collection de um Objeto fazendo calculos com BigDecimal

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho o atributo **valorTotal** este valor deve ser representado pela soma de todos os itens da classe Item que estão na lista **items**, estou tentando fazer a soma de todos os itens na lista que são BigDecimal, porém quando executo o valor é 0, ou seja, não está calculando, gostaria de entender isso.

```
package br.com.improving.carrinho;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class CarrinhoCompras {

    private  Collection<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private BigDecimal valorTotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    public CarrinhoCompras(Item item) {
        items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items.add(item);
    }

    public CarrinhoCompras() {

    }

    public void adicionarItem(Produto produto, BigDecimal valorUnitario, int quantidade) {

        Item item = new Item(produto, valorUnitario, quantidade);

        if (item != null) {
            items.add(item);
            }
    }

    public void adicionarItem(Item item) {
        if (item != null) {
            items.add(item);
        }

    }   

    public boolean removerItem(Produto produto) {

        Item item = new Item(produto );

            items.remove(item);

        return true;
        /*if(items.stream().anyMatch()
                        if (produto != null) {          
            this.items.remove(produto); 
        */
    }

   public boolean removerItem(int posicaoItem) {


            return true;
            }


    public BigDecimal getValorTotal() {

        items.forEach(item -> this.valorTotal.add(item.getValorTotal()));

        return this.valorTotal;
    }
```

.

Comment: Sua pergunta está meio confusa, tente melhora-la e apontar exatamente onde está dando o problema.

Comment: Fiz alterações já, me desculpem!

Answer (score 1):

`BigDecimal` é uma classe imutável, tal qual uma `String`, por exemplo. Isso quer dizer que você precisa armazenar o retorno do método invocado em uma variável, do contrário a computação realizada é perdida.

Aqui:

`this.valorTotal.add(item.getValorTotal())`

você faz a soma, mas não joga o retorno para a variável `valorTotal`, então a soma é perdida e `valorTotal` continua com o valor anterior, ou seja, zero.

Altere seu código na iteração para:

```
for(BigDecimal item: items) {
   valorTotal = valorTotal.add(item.getValorTotal());
}
```

Funções lambda só conseguem operar com variáveis constantes, ou seja, você não consegue, dentro uma função lambda, alterar uma variável que tenha sido declarada e inicializada fora dela, por isso o uso de um `foreach` tradicional.

Comment: Obrigado StatelessDev, eu havia tentado desta forma, mas por algum motivo não somava também, mas consegui sucesso fazendo o método dessa forma: BigDecimal valorTotal = items.stream().map(Item::getValorTotal)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);